# How to subscribe to an event calling listener on web3?

Tags: javascript, web3js, ethers.js

I have this method that subscribes a list of contracts to an event called 'Transfer' with a listener function. This is written in `ethers`. Now I am trying to refactor it to `web3.js`, how can I do it? I found the `once` method but It doesn't seems to work the same way.

```
async bindContracts() {
    const contractList: ContractEntity[] =
      await this.contractsRepository.find();

    this.contractProviders = contractList.map(
      (entity: ContractEntity) =>
        new ContractProvider(
          entity,
          new Contract(entity.address, entity.abi, this.provider),
        ),
    );
   
    this.contractProviders.forEach((provider) => {

      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv equivalent in web3.js?
      provider.contract.on(
        'Transfer',
        async (from: any, to: any, amount: any, event: any) => {
          if (from == '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000') {
            const tokenId = event.args.tokenId.toNumber();
            const to = event.args.to;
            const tokenURI = await provider.contract.tokenURI(tokenId);
            try {
              await this.createHero({
                uri: tokenURI,
                contract: provider.entity,
                creator: to,
                tokenId,
              });
            } catch (e) {
              throw e;
            }
          } else {
            const tokenId: number = event.args.tokenId.toNumber();
            const to: string = event.args.to;

            await this.updateUser(provider.entity.id, tokenId, to);
          }
        },
      );
    });
  }
```